# how to validate password and confirm password fields in sign up form using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am new in jsp programming.I develop sign up form in which I don't able to validate password and confirm password fields.When password and confirm password donot match it will go next page But it wrong.It check both field are equal then it goes to next page.And after sign up page data is inserted in db.
Please consider the following code.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("rpass").value;
        if (pass1 != pass2) {
            //alert("Passwords Do not match");
            document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
            document.getElementById("rpass").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        }
        else {
            alert("Passwords Match!!!");
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
<form method="post" id="regForm" onsubmit="return myFunction()" action="registration.jsp">

    First Name 
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />

    Email 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 

    Password</td>
    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" /> 

    Re Password 
    <input type="password" name="rpass" value="" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                                    
</form>
```

registration.jsp  Insert DB code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>

<%
    String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass,regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "',CURDATE())");
    if (i > 0) {
       out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='welcome.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementById()` method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.
without define Id how did you access `document`values
so define ID as well in all textfield and other fields like

```
 First Name 
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />

Email 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /> 

Password</td>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="" /> 

Re Password 
<input type="password" name="rpass" id="rpass" value="" />
```